# Yii form fields rendered twice

Tags: php, yii

The fields of my yii form in the register page are rendered twice!!
can anybody pls help me find out what's causing this?

here is the code from the controller:

```
public function actionRegister()
{
    $form=new Users;

            // collect user input data
            if(isset($_POST['Users']))
            {
                    $form->attributes=$_POST['Users']; // set all attributes with post
                    // NOTE Changes to any $form->value have to be performed BEFORE $form-validate()
                    // or else it won't save to the database. 

                    // validate user input and redirect to previous page if valid
                    if($form->validate())
                    {
                            // save user registration
                            $form->save();
                            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('site/login'));
                    }
            }
            // display the registration form
            $this->render('register',array('form'=>$form));  
}
```

here is the code from the view:

```
<?php $pagetitle = "Hubylon | Register"; ?>
<?php $this->breadcrumbs=array('Register'); ?>


<div class="yiiForm">
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm(); ?>

<?php echo CHtml::errorSummary($form); ?>

<div class="row">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>*<?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($form,'username'); ?>:</td>
            <td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($form,'username'); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo CHtml::error($form,'username',array('style' => 'color:red;font-size:11px;')); ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>*<?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($form,'password'); ?>:</td>
            <td><?php echo CHtml::activePasswordField($form,'password'); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo CHtml::error($form,'password',array('style' => 'color:red;font-size:11px;')); ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>*<?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($form,'confirmPassword'); ?>:</td>
            <td><?php echo CHtml::activePasswordField($form,'confirmPassword'); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo CHtml::error($form,'confirmPassword',array('style' => 'color:red;font-size:11px;')); ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($form,'first_name'); ?>:</td>
            <td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($form,'first_name'); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo CHtml::error($form,'first_name',array('style' => 'color:red;font-size:11px;')); ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($form,'birthdate'); ?>:</td>
            <td><?php 
                $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                    'attribute'=>'birthdate',
                    'model' => $form,
                    //'language'=>Yii::app()->language=='en' ? 'en' : null,
                    'options'=>array(
                        'dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd',
                        'defaultDate'=>$form->birthdate,
                        'buttonImage'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/icons.date.png',
                        'buttomImageOnly'=>true,
                        'showAnim'=>'fold',
                        'showOn'=>'button',
                        'yearRange'=>'1900',),
                    'htmlOptions'=>array(
                        'style'=>'width:80px;vertical-align:top'
                    ),
                ));
           ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="action">
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Register'); ?>
</div>

<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

thanks!

Comment: When you say "it displays twice", does that mean that the same view gets loaded and then auto-refreshes?

Comment: where abouts in the code is it repeated, are they literally one after the other, or is there other html output between the two forms?

Comment: no. the view is loaded once, but all the form's fields are displayed and right below them they're displayed again

Comment: @Stu , there is no html output between the forms

Comment: i managed to resolve it by adding the following line before the render:

    $this->layout = '//layouts/login';

not sure why and how it solved the problem.

thanks!!

Comment: Well, that's good. You can add an answer with that and even accept it so people face the same issue could find your solution http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking

Comment: @Nimir , i was trying to but i got a message that i have to wait 3 more hours till i can post it. so, for the meanwhile, i answered like this :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to resolve it by adding the following line before the render:

```
$this->layout = '//layouts/login';
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

seems there's no problem from the code you have given,
but maybe you can checkout the layouts and the `init()` method of the current controller.